# Error while read/write an image in Visual c++ using opencv 2.4.3

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I had followed the instructions of installing opencv using a youtube video.
First program was working fine.. I am using Visual studio 2010 and opencv 2.4.4

```
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>

using namespace cv;


int main()
{

    Mat image ;//=imread("C:\Users\Jango\Pictures\deepika-padukone-97a_4.jpg");
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);
    namedWindow("window",1);

    while(1)
    {
        cap>>image;
        imshow("window",image);

        waitKey(33);



    }
}
```

the video window is opening, and i can see the video on the webcam also. But when i tried the following program, i got many errors(the image path is correct)

```
    #include<opencv\cv.h>
    #include<opencv\highgui.h>

using namespace cv;


int main()
{

    Mat image =imread("C:\Users\Jango\Pictures\deepika-padukone-97a_4.jpg");
    //VideoCapture cap;
    //cap.open(0);
    namedWindow("window",1);

        imshow("window",image);

        waitKey(33);


        return 1;
    }
```

errors are

'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Jango\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\projects_opencv\mynewproject\Debug\mynewproject.exe', Symbols loaded.
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Jango\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\projects_opencv\mynewproject\Debug\opencv_core244d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Jango\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\projects_opencv\mynewproject\Debug\opencv_highgui244d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18201_none_ec80f00e8593ece5\comctl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avifil32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msacm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvfw32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avicap32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvinit.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Onekey Theater\ActiveDetect32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Onekey Theater\WindowsApiHookDll32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x684) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64\BtMmHook.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'mynewproject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
First-chance exception at 0x7712c41f (KernelBase.dll) in mynewproject.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0045e56c..
Unhandled exception at 0x7712c41f (KernelBase.dll) in mynewproject.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0045e56c..

follwoing are the screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: ignore the PDB warnings, but fix your imagepath:  C:/Users/Jango/Pictures/deepika-padukone-97a_4.jpg

Comment: Thanks @berak The imagepath is correct , i have checked it . I have edited the question n have some snapshot, just have a look.

Comment: Thanks,, i was going wrong with the forward slash.Fixed, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's the only problem, but the first thing to check is the line:

```
Mat image =imread("C:\Users\Jango\Pictures\deepika-padukone-97a_4.jpg");
```

Should be

```
Mat image =imread("C:\\Users\\Jango\\Pictures\\deepika-padukone-97a_4.jpg");
```